# ¿Cómo iterar sobre valores de una variable numérica usando case_when en R?

Tags: r, bucles, tidyverse

Tengo una base parecida a esto:

```
structure(list(id = c(110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 
110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 
110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 
110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 35, 45, 75, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 35, 45, 75
)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = "data.frame")
```

y quiero asignarle valores de cadena de caracteres utilizando `case_when` pero tratando de iterar sobre aquellos números que están dentro de un rango (en este caso del 110 al 115). Intentando algo como esto:

```
df %>%
   mutate(id= case_when(
          id == 35 ~ "algo",
          id == 45 ~ "otra_cosa",
          id == 75 ~ "otra_mas",
          between(id, 110, 115) ~  paste0("una_cosa", c(1:5)))) -> df_final
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `id = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! `between(id, 110, 115) ~ paste0("una_cosa_", c(1:5))` must be length 90
  or one, not 5.
Run `]8;;rstudio:run:rlang::last_error()rlang::last_error()]8;;` to see where the error occurred.
```

Entiendo que esto se refiere a que la instrucción que recibe `R` es de generar sólo un vector que diga "una_cosa_" con valores "una_cosa_1", "una_cosa_2", etc., pero no una iteración sobre los valores 110 a 115 en la variable id de forma tal que se modifique en el sentido deseado (es decir, si vale 110, que la etiqueta sea "una_cosa_1"; si es 111, que sea "una_cosa_2" y así sucesivamente).

Por tanto, intuyo que debo realizar un loop aunque en principio no sé si algo así sea posible dentro de `mutate()` y `case_when()` por lo que agradeceré cualquier orientación al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está con:

```
between(id, 110, 115) ~  paste0("una_cosa", c(1:5))
```

Por lo que dice el error, hay 90 elementos en el rango 110-115 y solo 5 valores de reemplazo, lo que retorna `paste0("una_cosa", c(1:5))`. La única forma es que retornes 90 elementos o en todo caso 1 para todo el grupo. El otro problema es como hacer el "match" entre estos 5 (en realidad 6) valores y cada `id`. Lo que se me ocurre, en este caso es algo así:

```
df %>%
  mutate(id= case_when(
    id == 35 ~ "algo",
    id == 45 ~ "otra_cosa",
    id == 75 ~ "otra_mas",
    between(id, 110, 115) ~  paste0("una_cosa_", id - 109)
  )
)
```

Comment: Funcionó de maravilla. Ni por asomo pensé que la solución fuera así de limpia. Muchas gracias, como siempre.